# Java, how to convert a string to class and call its static method?

Tags: java

```
class Item
{
    public static test()
    {
    }
}

String s = "package.Item";
Item o = (Item)Class.forName(s).cast(Item.class); // *
o.test();
```

but the marked line fails:

java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast java.lang.Class to items.Item

Comment: `Class.forName()` returns a `Class` object, not an instance of that class.

Comment: oh, I dont need an instance sorry!

Comment: Doesn't even compile..

Comment: Then you want a `Class<Item>` not a `Item`

Comment: And you won't be able to call the `test` method like that, you'll have to use Reflection.

Comment: @AxelH excatly how?

Comment: Why do you want instance if the method is static? Does it make sense ?

Comment: how many times should I say I do NOT want an instance?

Comment: Jesus whats up with people and the down votes. This is not a bad question at all. Actually its pretty much of something to keep in mind and learn about i will love for the proper answer so that i can implement this next time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create new instance you need to do the following

```
Class c = Class.forName("Item");
Item i = (Item)c.newInstance();
```

If you want to invoke static method you just call it on class instead of instance

```
Item.test();
```

Or you can use reflection without directly reference to class

```
Class c = Class.forName("Item");
Method method = c.getMethod("test");
method.invoke(null);
```

Comment: He can't call Item.test() since he receive Item into a String.. he need reflexion to get the methods (test) from the Class

Comment: In his sample code he use `Item`. Of course his code doesn't have sense, but I work with what I have.

Comment: It's in the title `how to convert a string to class and call its static method?` Item that he tried to create from the String ;)

Comment: I added reflection code for completeness.

Comment: It is a duplicated question ... no need for an answer ;)

Comment: It is poorly stated question :)

Comment: yes, there was a need for an answer... I coulnt know that I need this line too: "Method method = c.getMethod("test");", I thought somehow c.test can be invoked, by casting